# jQgrid Drop Down Menu Not Populating Data in Form Edit

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jqgrid, edit

So I wasted a whole day tracing data but couldnt find solution so posting here.
Below is my **js** code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jq(function() {
        jq("#Grid").jqGrid({
            url:'/indyaah/crud.htm',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:['User Id','User Name','Book Id','Book Name'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'userId',index:'userId', formatter: 'select', stype: 'select',edittype: 'select',editoptions:{value:Users()},editable:true, editrules:{required:true,edithidden:true},searchoptions:{sopt: ['eq','ne','le','ge']},hidden:true},
                {name:'userName',index:'userName', width:100,editable:false},
                {name:'bookId',index:'bookId', formatter: 'select', stype: 'select',edittype: 'select',editoptions:{value:Books()},editable:true, editrules:{required:true,edithidden:true},searchoptions:{sopt: ['eq','ne','le','ge']},hidden:true},
                {name:'BookName',index:'BookName', width:100},
                ],
            postData: { 
            },
            rowNum:5,
            altRows:true,
            hiddengrid:true,
            rowList:[5,10],
            height: "100%",
            autowidth: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'userId',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption:"Details",
            emptyrecords: "Empty records",
            loadonce: false,
            autowidth:true,
            loadComplete: function() {
            },
            jsonReader : {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                cell: "cell",
                id: "id"
            }
        });
        function Users()
        {
            jq.getJSON('/indyaah/readUsers.htm', function(data) {
            var len = data.rows.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if(i===0) html += '' + data.rows[i].userId + ' : \'' + data.rows[i].userName + '\',' ;
                else if(i===len-1) html +=  data.rows[i].userId + ' : \'' + data.rows[i].userName + '\'' ;
                else html += data.rows[i].userId + ' : \'' + data.rows[i].userName + '\',' ;
            }   
            });
            return html;
        }
        function Books()
        {
            jq.getJSON('/indyaah/readBooks.htm', function(data) {
            var len = data.rows.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if(i===0) html += '{\'' + data.rows[i].bookId + '\':\'' + data.rows[i].name + '\',\n' ;
                else if(i===len-1) html += '\''+ data.rows[i].bookId + '\':\'' + data.rows[i].name + '\'}' ;
                else html += '\''+ data.rows[i].bookId + '\':\'' + data.rows[i].name + '\',\n' ;
            }
            });
            return html;
        }
        jq("#Grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
                {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true},
                { },
                { },
                { }, 
                { 
                    sopt:['eq', 'ne', 'le', 'ge', 'cn', 'bw', 'ew'],
                    closeOnEscape: true, 
                        multipleSearch: true, 
                        closeAfterSearch: true },
                {width:500}
        );      
        jq("#Grid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
                {   caption:"Add", 
                    buttonicon:"ui-icon-plus", 
                    onClickButton: add,
                    position: "last", 
                    title:"", 
                    cursor: "pointer"
                } 
        );

        jq("#Grid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
                {   caption:"Edit", 
                    buttonicon:"ui-icon-pencil", 
                    onClickButton: edit,
                    position: "last", 
                    title:"", 
                    cursor: "pointer"
                } 
        );

        jq("#Grid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
            {   caption:"Delete", 
                buttonicon:"ui-icon-trash", 
                onClickButton: delete,
                position: "last", 
                title:"", 
                cursor: "pointer"
            } 
        );

        jq("#btnFilter").click(function(){
            jq("#Grid").jqGrid('searchGrid',
                    {multipleSearch: true, 
                        sopt:['eq']}
            );
        });


        jq("#Grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true, defaultSearch:"cn"});

    });
</script>
```

both the Jsons have following format (i have shown only 3-4 columns but there are 8 and 10 respectively),

```
{
page: 1
records: 5
rows: [
        0: {displayName:ABC, password:null, userName:123, userId:1,…}
        1: {displayName:DEF, password:null, userName:456, userId:2,…}
        2: {displayName:GHI, password:null, userName:789, userId:3,…}
        3: {displayName:JKL, password:null, userName:234, userId:4,…}
        4: {displayName:MNO, password:null, userName:548, userId:5,…}
        5: {displayName:PQR, password:null, userName:968, userId:6,…}
]
}
```

and

```
{
page: 1
records: 5
rows: [
        0: {displayName:ABC,  bookName:123, bookId:1,…}
        1: {displayName:DEF,  bookName:456, bookId:2,…}
        2: {displayName:GHI,  bookName:789, bookId:3,…}
        3: {displayName:JKL,  bookName:234, bookId:4,…}
        4: {displayName:MNO,  bookName:548, bookId:5,…}
        5: {displayName:PQR,  bookName:968, bookId:6,…}
]
}
```

My Edit/Add form looks like [image: this]
Note that In Edit/Add I use only some of the values sent in Json by the server.!

**So basically the problem is that the grid is loaded perfectly but as soon as i try to add or edit,
the select boxes are empty.**
When i debugged in firebug, the Controller sends the data but it is not loaded in to grid.

So, what am i missing here??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of your problem is clear, but the solution is not so easy, because the usage of `formatter: 'select'` together with `editoptions.value` loaded from the server is not really supported by jqGrid. I try to describe the origin of your problem and describe the ways of solution.

The first problem is that `$.getJSON` works *asynchronous*. So if the `Users()` or `Books()` will be called the `undefined` value will be returned from the functions. By the way the `html` variable is really undefined in your code.

I can suggest some ways to solve your current problem.

You can just remove the `edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: Users()}, editable: true` and `edittype: 'select' ,editoptions: {value: Books()}, editable: true` from the column definition. You can set the settings inside of `success` handler of the corresponding `$.getJSON` calls:

```js
jq("#Grid").jqGrid({
    ...
});
jq.getJSON('/indyaah/readUsers.htm', function (data) {
    var len = data.rows.length, i, html = '', item;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        item = data.rows[i];
        if (i !== 0) {
            html += ',';
        }
        html += item.userId + ":'" + item.userName + "'";
    }
    jq("#Grid").jqGrid('setColProp', 'userId', {
        edittype: 'select',
        editoptions: {value: html},
        editable: true
    });
});
jq.getJSON('/indyaah/readBooks.htm', function (data) {
    ...
    jq("#Grid").jqGrid('setColProp', 'bookId', {
        edittype: 'select',
        editoptions: {value: html},
        editable: true
    });
});
```

At the moment when the Add or Edit form will be opened, the correct value for `editoptions.value` will be already in the `colModel` and the selects should be displayed correctly.

The problem which you will still have is the usage of `formatter: 'select'` which need `editoptions.value` **to be fill before the filling of the grid body**. You wrote that the grid was filled correctly. I think that it means that the requests to '/indyaah/readUsers.htm' and '/indyaah/readBooks.htm' was answered by the server **before** '/indyaah/crud.htm'. I find it dangerous.

So I would recommend you to use first `datatype: 'local'` option in the jqGrid. It will prevent the grid loading. You should set `datatype: 'json'` and call `jq("#Grid").trigger("reloadGrid")` **after** the all selects (both selects) of the `colModel` are loaded. The corresponding implementation is easy. For example:

```js
var filledSelects = 0,
    $grid = jq("#Grid");
    fillSelectWithData = function (data, colName, idProp, nameProp) {
        var len = data.rows.length, i, html = '', item;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            item = data.rows[i];
            if (i !== 0) {
                html += ',';
            }
            html += item[idProp] + ":'" + item[nameProp] + "'";
        }
        $grid.jqGrid('setColProp', colName, {
            edittype: 'select',
            editoptions: {value: html},
            editable: true
        });
    },
    loadGridIfRequired = function () {
        filledSelects++;
        if (filledSelects > 1) {
            $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                datatype: 'json'
            }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        }
    };

$grid.jqGrid({
    url:'/indyaah/crud.htm',
    datatype: 'local'
    ...
});
jq.getJSON('/indyaah/readUsers.htm', function (data) {
    fillSelectWithData(data, 'userId', 'userId', 'userName');
    loadGridIfRequired();
});
jq.ajax('/indyaah/readBooks.htm', function (data) {
    fillSelectWithData(data, 'bookId', 'bookId', 'user');
    loadGridIfRequired();
});
```

All above code is untested, but I hope that it will work (probably after small bug fixing.)

Comment: you're the man buddy...
i mean every single jqgrid question i have seen, you are there with TO THE POINT answer and perfect description..
Thanks for this one too, i ll let you know when i have tested.. **respect**

Comment: @indyaah: You are welcome! Thanks for the good words about me!

Comment: i tested the code, it returns complete html object as single drop down option instead of seperate options.
i.e : when i edit it give one option in dropdown which looks like 1:'abc',2:'def',...